# WPF Image - Source can't resolve an image resource from other project

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, uri

I'm trying to use an image in WPF/XAML with a source pointing to a resource contained in another project:

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/MySolution.Resources;component/myicon.png" />
```

But when I run the application, the image doesn't appear and the source isn't resolved.

Here's how I've got the image set up in the MySolution.Resources project (a library project which is referenced as a dependency by the shell project containing the XAML):

[image: myicon properties]

I have also tried with copy to output set to 'newest', but no luck. It even auto-completes the image name when I type the path as seen above in XAML, suggesting it knows the resource exists, but it just won't work at runtime:

[image: autocomplete]

Also it works fine if I use the same image but placed in the shell project alongside the XAML. Any ideas why it might not be working? I tried a clean/rebuild/restart too - nothing.

Comment: Is `MySolution.Resources` a valid assembly name, not to be confused with the project name of the class library?

Comment: For "*suggesting **it** knows the resource exists*" - the **it** are different things in design mode and in runtime.

Comment: Yes I think it's a valid assembly - the output in the bin folder is 'MySolution.Resources.dll'. @Clemens - ah OK, maybe that's not relevant then.

Comment: What you are showing here should just work. When you say "*shell project*" you mean the application project that references the library project?

Comment: Yeah, the shell is basically the main WPF project and entry point that then references the resources. I created a very [minimal demo app](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/gaoz6xyc2ww7wyrekszbl/ImageResourceTest.zip?rlkey=g416hmq5mq6wguuruxhfdlswx&dl=0) which shows the set up, and also has the same problem if anyone's interested!

Comment: There must be `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>` in Resources.csproj. Otherwise the image file can not be loaded by a WPF Resource File Pack URI.